# Two files into one column in C Program

Tags: c, file, fclose

I am trying to figure it out why am I still getting error message when I did my `gcc` command on terminal and I have also both included for code and compiler as well. Can anyone have any idea why or can help me for me? I am really new to C Program this semester. This is a main function that takes command line argument that opens two files and combines the two files one line at a time into one output. The first file are lines of text, but remove any trailing white spaces from the end of each line (newlines, tabs and spaces), and the second files are the list of numbers. So there should be two columns separated by a character. I have them for example so you can visual for more clarification:

```
  Example for to output:
  ./p2 test/p2-testa test/p2-testb
  Test A  11
  Test B  51
  Test C  91
  Test D  26
  Test E  17
  Test F  76


/* 3 point */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAXLEN = 4096;
const int MAXLINES = 10;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char buffer[MAXLEN];
  char buffer2[MAXLEN];
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

  if (!(fp && fp2)) {
    perror ("Not Found");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int n = 0;
  while((n < MAXLINES) && (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp)) && (fgets(buffer2, sizeof (buffer2), fp2))) {
    printf("%s\t%s", buffer, buffer2);
    n++;
  }

  fclose((fp) && (fp2));    
  return (0);

}
```

ERROR COMPILE MESSAGE (BTW: For lecture, I used `labcheck` by instructor):

```
p2:
p2.c: In function ‘main’:
p2.c:52:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fclose’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       fclose((fp) && (fp2));
              ~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from p2.c:2:
/usr/include/stdio.h:199:26: note: expected ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’} but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
                    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
-3.0 output of program (p2) is not correct for input '/u1/h7/CS151/.check/text/list.1 /u1/h7/CS151/.check/nums/tiny.1':
------ Yours: ------
---- Reference: ----
Line A  6
Line B  41
Line C  52
Line D  3
Line E  36
Line F  61
--------------------
```

I didn't really understand the warning and expected message in C program.

Comment: Really not cool to create 2 questions on the platform for the same problem! in less than an hour interval!!

Answer (score 4):

Expression `(fp) && (fp2)` passed to `fclose` combines two pointers by operator `&&`, which expects integral operands and interprets them as beeing either `==0` or `!=0`. The result is an integral value, which again is either `==0` or `!=0`, but it has nothing to do any more with the pointers `fclose` expects.

So `fclose((fp) && (fp2))` should be

```
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
```

Comment: you beat me to it - cool!  1) As you said, the OP needs to make two separate calls to `fclose)` - he can't just close two file pointers at the same time.  2) The "expected" message is probably coming from labcheck.  The problem there is probably incorrect output: the OP *ALSO* needs to add some code to "trim" the raw output from fgets().

Answer (score -2):

your program should look exactly like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAXLEN = 4096;
const int MAXLINES = 10;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char buffer[MAXLEN];
  char buffer2[MAXLEN];
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

  if (!(fp && fp2)) {
    perror ("Not Found");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

     int n = 0;
       while((n < MAXLINES) && (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp)) && (fgets(buffer2, sizeof (buffer2), fp2))) {
           printf("%s\t%s", buffer, buffer2);
               n++;

}
      fclose(fp);
      fclose(fp2);

      return (0);

      }
```

Comment: Q: Have you actually tried this, with test files?  Do you get the expected results?  Do the rows line up?